Grounding issue with PWM fan controller on Raspberry Pi Pico to drive 12 VDC fan
I'm trying to build a PWM fan controller for an industrial Noctua PWM Fan (NF-F12 IndustrialPPC 3000 PWM). You'll find the schematic below.
The fan is powered by a 12 VDC power supply (V1) (during testing, it's powered by my bench power supply).
The Raspberry Pi Pico is powered via the USB port (5 VDC).
The Pico creates the PWM signal for the fan (on pin GP16). It's a standard 25 KHz frequency PWM signal with a configurable duty cycle from 25% to 100% (via a rotary encoder, not pictured in the schematic below). The PWM signal is correctly generated (I've ensured that by checking it with my oscilloscope and Saleae logic analyzer). The PWM signal is properly inverted in the firmware (required due to the BJT). See logic analyzer screenshot below.
The circuit works with a 12 V PC fan from Fractal, but it doesn't work for the Noctua fan (it spins at 100%).
I believe the issue comes from the fact that there is no common ground between the 12 VDC supply (V1) for the fan and the PWM signal. In a previous test iteration, I connected the emitter of the BJT (Q1) to the GND of V1. However, doing so seems to have fried the output stage of the GPIOs that I was using earlier.
How do I best achieve a common ground for the PWM signal?
Thank you!





First, don't connect a local 3.3V pull-up to the NPN. It's unnecessary (the fan has its own pull up internally) and it creates a Vcc leak path to the Pico.
The fan will make a lot of noise on its GND line, so it's really important that it have a low-impedance return path to 12V. Tie your grounds together (12V, 5V, fan, Pico) in a 'star' to a common, low-impedance return.
You also could consider using an optoisolator for your Pico to drive the PWM. Then the 5V and 12V systems can be completely separated.

So, if I understood you correctly, you're suggesting a circuit like the following? https://imgur.com/3Tq7iLS

Although, the Noctua specifications (https://noctua.at/pub/media/wysiwyg/Noctua_PWM_specifications_white_paper.pdf) suggest against using a BJT; therefore, I could remove that and just tie the GPIO output directly to the PWM signal? https://imgur.com/Z5FtuED

The circuit above is tested and confirmed working! Thank you!

Simply combine the GNDs from both your 12 V supply and your Pi Pico.  Tie them directly together.  This is the normal way to do it.
The fan internally pulls the PWM high, so you shouldn't do that externally.  You just need to provide an open drain/collector.  Remove R1 from the circuit, and do not connect pin 36 on your Pi to anything.
Consider replacing Q1 with a logic-level N-MOSFET if you experience erratic behavior.

Regarding the PWM Control Input Signal, Intel's 4-Wire Pulse Width Modulation (PWM) Controlled Fans Specification section 2.1.4 says "This signal must be pulled up to a maximum of 5.25V within the fan. Note: New fan designs are strongly encouraged to implement a 3.3V pull up for compatibility with buffer design limits on Hardware Monitor Devices e.g. Super IO devices." So 3.3 V should be fine with a modern Noctua fan.

@AndrewMorton This makes me worry the fan is internally pulled up to 5 V ("within" the fan).  Your link states that such a fan requires an open-drain or open-collector PWM.  This may be why OP is damaging his I/O, as he is providing 5 V to his 3.3 V output.

@evildemonic The specifications for the PWM implementation from Noctua state: "External pull-up is not necessary as the signal is pulled up to 3,3V/5V inside the fan." Therefore, I assume the 3.3 V logic will work. Or am I seeing this incorrectly?
(source: https://noctua.at/pub/media/wysiwyg/Noctua_PWM_specifications_white_paper.pdf // page 6)

It will work, BUT you need to not connect your own pullup (which you are doing in your schematic) because that will expose your 3.3V IO to 5V which will damage them over time.  Remove R1 and the connection to pin 36, combine your grounds, and you should be good to go.

Ground needs to be connected between the fan and the controlling circuit.
Further, there must be no external pull-up resistor: see Intel's 4-Wire Pulse Width Modulation (PWM) Controlled Fans Specification, section 2.4 (Considerations for Motherboard Designers), item 1:

The trace from PWM output to the fan header must not have a pull up or pull down. The pull up is located in the fan hub. The presence of a pull up on the motherboard will alter the fan response to the PWM Duty Cycle. In some cases this may prevent the fan from achieving full speed even with the Hardware Monitor device issuing a 100% duty cycle.

Although Intel's spec suggests using an open collector design, Noctua PWM specifications white paper recommends against that:

There are no special requirements for the circuits that generate the PWM signal. However, Noctua recommends to use a CMOS-inverter type circuit as shown below. This is the very circuit that is used for GPIO pins inside most micro-controllers.

[Please see the white paper for the image - it might be a bit much for me to include that as well as the text.]

Open collector designs as shown below are not recommended, because as there is very little current sourced from the fan the waveform may become deformed. This can lead to erroneous fan behavior.

[The white paper has an image showing a deformed square wave to illustrate that.]
